# Send HTTP GET/POST via a reverse proxy that requires client certificates

Tags: reverse-proxy, gatling, client-certificates

I am trying to send http GET/POST requests to applications that are hidden behind a reverse proxy. Communication with the reverse proxy is via https and the proxy requires a client certificate.

It looks like that the keystore certificate (gatling.http.ssl.keyStore.file) is not used to authenticate with the reverse proxy. I assume this because:

- if I request https://reverse-proxy-address without specifying a proxy, I receive an answer (basically the same as if I access the URL within a browser with the client certificate) -> certificate is used for the request.
- if I specify a proxy with http.proxy(Proxy("reverse-proxy-address", port)) and sent a request to http://hidden-url I receive a "org.asynchttpclient.exception.RemotelyClosedException: Remotely closed" (Gatling 2.3.1) or "java.io.IOException: Premature close" (Gatling 3.0.3)

I haven't found a hint how I can specify that the client certificate is used for authentication with the reverse proxy. Maybe the client certificate is already used to authenticate with the reverse proxy and something else is not configured correctly. I don't know how to analyze further...

Hope that someone else already faced the same issue and know the solution. Also hints so that I can dig deeper are more than welcome!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was doing that with Gatling 2.x on OSX. It requires a few steps more. Setting cert path in gatling.conf is not enough.

I received CRT.pem and KEY.pem files. I created p12 cert based on the key pair.

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in client1-crt.pem -inkey client1-key.pem -out cert.p12
```

Then I created store and imported the cert to keystore.

```
keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass mycert -destkeystore filename-new-keystore.jks -srckeystore cert.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12
```

The next step is to set correct path in gatling.conf (it depends on OS)

my gatling conf:

```
gatling {
  http {
    ssl {
      keyStore {
        type = "PKCS12"
        file = "/Users/lukasz/cert.p12"
        password = ""
      }
      trustStore {
        type = ""
        file = "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_111.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts"
        password = "changeit"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This way I was able to use custom certificate with Gatling. I'm not sure if this is a workaround or this is a proper way to handle custom certificate by JVM.